# How to get names of the columns from PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I want to encrypt the values assigned to some columns using prepared Statement's set methods ? For that I must fetch the columnnames from pre compiled preaparedStatement. How can I do that ?

I have tried getting ResultSetMetaData but using method getMetaData() but I always get null value. getParameterMetaData() is not null but of no use for getting the column names.

Is there any other way to get the real db column names from preparedStatement before setting the parameters ?

> Java Docs for ResultSetMetaData say that getMetaData() returns the
>   description of a ResultSet object's columns or null if the driver
>   cannot return a ResultSetMetaData object.

However in my case if I remove call to getMetaData() everything works perfectly, so it is possible that prepared statement behaves normally and executest even if driver is unable to return an object of meta data ?
**EDIT 1**
I am working on a JDBC driver which will be used with MySQL and MSSQL. Currently I am testing only on MySQL.

Comment: What is your SQL statement? and what database are you using

Comment: Side question: why would you write a single JDBC driver to access MySQL and MS SQL. The way JDBC is defined that is entirely unnecessary: drivers are loaded dynamically and used if they support a specific URL.

Comment: You might also want to provide more information: which driver has this behavior, and include the code necessary to demonstrate this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel actually I have some common code (like encryption/decryyption) which I want to use for before each call to set<X>() method of preparedStatement and get<X> method of resultset.. That way I will handle encryption and decryption inside driver code while other teams won't even need to know it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694926/jdbc4preparedstatement-vs-serverpreparedstatement?rq=1

Comment: Encryption doesn't belong in a JDBC driver. The programmer can express the encryption [directly in SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html).

Comment: @EJP That is a database specific solution, and it doesn't "help" if you don't want the unencrypted content known outside your own program.